# Posting on friend's wall

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api

How do I post to friend's wall using PHP Graph API? I got some javascript solutions. But I need PHP ones. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check the documentation here http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/post/.

Try `$facebook->api('/Friend_ID/feed','post',array('message'=$message));`. Refer to the documention for more parameters.

Answer (score 1):

it requires few things
Create a Facebook Application: FB Documentation
Request extended permissions to access a user's photos and their friend's photos Facebook Auth / Permissions
FQL + JSDK to request the data JSDK Doc

```
$attachment = array('message' => 'this is my message',
            'name' => 'This is my demo Facebook application!',
            'caption' => "Caption of the Post",
            'link' => 'http://mylink.com',
            'description' => 'this is a description',
            'picture' => 'http://mysite.com/pic.gif',
            'actions' => array(array('name' => 'Get Search',
                              'link' => 'http://www.google.com'))
            );


$result = $facebook->api('/me/feed/',
                            'post',
                            $attachment);

good luck
```

Comment: but this will post to your own wall won't it?